# Possible memory leak in priority queue?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, priority-queue

I am using C++ priority queue and I have to clear the priority queue each time the iteration takes place. As there is no clear function already defined for priority queue I tried a method like this

```
priority_queue <int> fpq;
while(condition)
{
    //Resetting fpq for each iteration
    fpq=priority_queue<int>();      //Possible memory leak
 //modified fpq
}
```

Where fpq is an existing object and I am putting in it a new priority queue (which is empty) using its constructor. My question is that will it lead to a memory leak as the memory allocated before to fpq before this line of code is not deallocated explicitly. Or is that taken care of?

Comment: Can you just let RAII take care of it by automatically calling the `fpq` destructor when it goes out of scope? If you are concerned about leaking memory try to run the code through valgrind.

Comment: Standard library containers and container adaptors manage their own storage space. There's no leak in the posted code.

Answer (score 1):

The priority_queue destructor and/or copy constructor takes care of freeing unused memory prior to copying over the new (empty) priority_queue, so there are no leaks in the code you wrote.

This is true for all standard container objects, so you can safely use them without worrying about memory leaks.